# ASP.NET doesn't publish new site

Tags: asp.net, web, overwrite

I developed my web project in Visual Studio. Then I tested the site on local server.

Then I deleted **bin folder**, **aspx pages**, **web.config**, **PreCompiledApp.config** files on server and uploaded the new files (from the updated project).

Bud server keeps showing old project. I don't want to delete everything on server. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is this on a server with IIS? What happens if you go on the server and browse the site directly. Are you getting the new site?

Comment: Yes, with IIS server. I get the same result when I browse the site from hosting control panel.

Comment: I fix the problem. I uploaded the new files on server via FileZilla. The problem is FileZilla. Server keeping old file entries when the new file uploaded that named with old one. I uploaded the new files with browser and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

That is either due to the caching on the Server and Browser or either the files that want to save on the server side.

Try removing all the cookies from your Browser and then reloading the page. This time the page would be reloaded once again from the Server and the new page would be there. This way, all the pages would be reloaded and this time the new pages would be loaded to the Browser.